# Custom hostname for docker host from within container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

My company has recently started dockerizing some of our services to be spun up by other teams in dev. Several services talk to the main app, and the main app will not be run in docker as that's what people primarily develop against. These services must communicate via hostname; ip address and port alone won't work because we use subdomains to determine the account a user is speaking to.

I know docker exposes `docker.host.internal` for communication to the host, but we need to be able to specify that hostname so it's not sufficient.

I've tried setting up a custom network and applying it to the services that need to speak back to get a static host ip, then using the extra_hosts field to specify hostname, but haven't gotten to the point where I can curl that static ip from within the container.

Here's an outline of our `docker-compose.yml`

```
networks:  
  local:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.0.0/24
          gateway: 10.0.0.1

services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: ../myservice
    networks:
      - local
    extra_hosts:
      - "myaccount.mycompany.io:10.0.0.1"
```

On the host machine, we have an haproxy setup to route hosts to the proper port.

From within the myservice container, `curl 10.0.0.1` and `curl myaccount.mycompany.io` are both unable to resolve, but `curl docker.host.internal` does.

Any thoughts on what's wrong with this setup or other approaches we could take?

Thanks a bunch

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble following the question. Are you having trouble reaching your docker services via hostnames? Or you're trying to reach your docker host from within a container?

Comment: Can you use an environment variable to specify the host name that will be used?  (And delete all of the `networks:` and `extra_hosts:` setup, and never touch `/etc/hosts` at all?)

Comment: @im_baby it's not a problem of reaching the services, it's that I need the services to reach the host, but the services need to reach the host with a specific hostname i.e. myaccount.mycompany.io instead of docker.host.internal.

Comment: @DavidMaze Maybe, but I'm not sure how that would look. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @user2836307 your service containers should be able to reach network with no extra config. Don't think about it as trying to reach the underlying host, instead they're just trying to reach another resource on the network. Is you main app publicly accessible or only internal?

Comment: @im_baby the main app is running on the host machine and isn't accessible publicly

Comment: Can you curl the main app from your machine while on the company network?